# iOS: Open Map app with directions

Tags: ios, dictionary, direction

It's posible with help of MKMapItem to open Map application with two points provided, but user should tap on Start button in top-right corner anyway. Is it possible to skip this step and proceed to turn-by-turn voice navigation immediately? So far only posible way I know is to use private framework to generate touch event, but I need more legal solution.

Comment: No this is not possible. The api does not offer an option to do this.

Comment: You can do this with google maps API. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme